# can not access http://192.168.56.1:3000 from mobile device while using browsersync

Tags: browser-sync

I have installed browsersync using command npm install -g browser-sync in windows 10 x64. nodejs version 10.11.0 browsersync version 2.26.3

everything is working fine in desktop. but when i try to access http://192.168.56.1:3000 from mobile device using same wifi, i get "this site can't be reached"

i have installed another tool named dev-ip which returns this in powershell:
[ '192.168.56.1', '192.168.0.120' ]

the ip series 192.168.0.120 used to work fine in my mobile devices.

now, how to use the ip 192.168.0.120 instead of 192.168.56.1 in browsersync globally?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the host in your configuration that you want the server to run on.

Eg. In you case it would be 
host: "192.168.0.120"

You can refer to the link below for more information.

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-host

Answer (score 0):

*Hi, guys*. This is how it worked for me:

**Source:**

- windows 10
- all firewalls are closed
- network access (from windows) to the PC is disabled
- external url from gulp *192.168.56.1:3000*
- proxying local php site from OpenServer
- external device - iphone safari/chrome
- external (virtual) device - vwware with macos
- make sure that *Windows Defender firewall monitor in high-risk mode* -> *rules for incoming connections* -> *Node.js: Server-side JavaScript* **is enabled** (and other necessary apps)
  [image]

**Solution:**

1. look at what ip address in the home network my PC has (all devices are connected to the same network) - for example *192.168.1.103*
2. in the gulp file I specify it `host: "192.168.1.103",`
3. save
4. checking it out

**Important:**

- for source  *- external device - iphone safari/chrome* - correct url is only **192.168.1.103:3000**
- for source  *- external (virtual) device - vwware with macos* - correct urls is **192.168.1.103:3000** and **192.168.56.1:3000** both

Visually in pic:
[image]

**Result:**

Checked on all devices, in virtual devices, on the PC itself

- browsersync works
- the Internet is not lost
- there is no address conflict within the network

Hope this will help someone too

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the settings.

1. run cmd using Administrator
2. run **ipconfig**
3. copy IPv4 address like 192.168.43.52
4. Now open google on mobile and add **http://** at the front and **:3000** or **:5500** at the back.
   like run **http://192.168.43.52:3000**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).